# Why does dask.bag.read_text(filename).map(json.loads) return a list?

Tags: json, python-3.x, dask

I need to read several json.gz files using Dask. I am trying to achieve this by using dask.bag.read_text(filename).map(json.loads), but the output is a nested list (the files contain lists of dictionaries), whereas I would like to get a just a list of dictionaries.

I have included a small example that reproduces my problem, below.

```py
import json 
import gzip
import dask.bag as db

dict_list = [{'id': 123, 'name': 'lemurt', 'indices': [1,10]}, {'id': 345, 'name': 'katin', 'indices': [2,11]}]

filename = './test.json.gz'

# Write json
with gzip.open(filename, 'wt') as write_file:
    json.dump(dict_list , write_file)

# Read json
with gzip.open(filename, "r") as read_file:
    data = json.load(read_file)

# Read json with Dask 
data_dask = db.read_text(filename).map(json.loads).compute()

print(data)
print(data_dask)
```

I would like to get the first output:

```py
[{'id': 123, 'name': 'lemurt', 'indices': [1, 10]}, {'id': 345, 'name': 'katin', 'indices': [2, 11]}]
```

But instead I get the second one:

```py
[[{'id': 123, 'name': 'lemurt', 'indices': [1, 10]}, {'id': 345, 'name': 'katin', 'indices': [2, 11]}]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The read_text function returns a bag, where each element is a line of text.  So you have a list of strings.  Then, you parse each of those lines of text with `json.loads`, so each of those lines of text becomes a list again.  So you have a list of lists.

In your case you might use map_partitions, and a function that expects a list of a single line of text

```
b = db.read_text("*.json.gz").map(lambda L: json.loads(L[0]))
```

Comment: Thanks @MRocklin for the reply. I am new to Dask and I probably misunderstood your suggestion, but `db.read_text("*.json.gz").map(lambda L: json.loads(L[0]))` gives me JSONDecodeError. 

The way I ended up solving my problem is by writing one dictionary per line in the json file. I will add that as an answer to my question, but many thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Following the comment by @MRocklin, I ended up solving my problem by changing the way I was writing the json.gz files.

Instead of

```py
with gzip.open(filename, 'wt') as write_file:
    json.dump(dict_list , write_file)
```

I used

```py
with gzip.open(filename, 'wt') as write_file:
    for dd in dict_list:
        json.dump(dd , write_file)
        write_file.write("\n")
```

and kept reading the files as

```py
db.read_text(filename).map(json.loads)
```